# How do I add a subtotal/grand total to a Power BI matrix that includes only one column?

Tags: powerbi

I have a matrix that looks like this:

| Location | City A |  | City B |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Series** | **Bus Numbers** | **Count** | **Bus Numbers** | **Count** |
| X | 1, 2, 3, 4 | 4 | 6, 7, 5 | 3 |
| Y | 2 | 1 | 3, 9, 5 | 3 |

Where "Series" is in the rows category, "Location" is in the columns category, and "Bus Numbers" and "Count" are in the values category. "Bus Numbers" is a measure that concatenates the bus numbers (so I can see them all listed in the cell), so when I add grand totals/subtotals to the matrix it gives both a giant list of all the buses and the "Count" totals. All I want are the totals for "Count", but I can't seem to find a way to have it without the buses being in there too. This is what I want it to look like:

| Location | City A |  | City B |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Series** | **Bus Numbers** | **Count** | **Bus Numbers** | **Count** | **Total** |
| X | 1, 2, 3, 4 | 4 | 6, 7, 5 | 3 | 7 |
| Y | 2 | 1 | 3, 9, 5 | 3 | 4 |
| **Total** |  | 5 |  | 6 | 11 |

I tried to add a new measure that sums "Count", but it was essentially a duplicate of "Count", not a grand total. I also tried to do a format that whites out the Bus Numbers grand total, but it didn't go away, it was just all white. I tried to find a custom visual, and Inforiver actually had a matrix format that let me do this, but I can't use it because it's not free.